# Jquery problems with calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So i'm trying to make a function, that sets / removes the watermark in an  field, i have gotten this working, where the input html elements looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="pollName" id="pollName" value="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="javascript: watermark(this,true,'DD-MM-YYYY')" onblur="javascript: watermark(this,false,'DD-MM-YYYY')" >
```

This however is painfully long, and i'm trying to move the code to javascript, where i intend to use this code:

```
function watermark(dom,isFocus,watermark)
{
    if(isFocus)
    {
        if(dom.value === watermark)
        {
            dom.value = "";
        }
    }
    else if(!isFocus)
    {
        if(dom.value === '')
        {
            dom.value = watermark;
        }
    }
}

document.ready(function(){
    $('#addOption').click(addOption);
    $('.dateSelector').focusin(watermark(this,1,'DD-MM-YYYY'));
    $('.dateSelector').focusout(watermark(this,0,'DD-MM-YYYY'));
});
```

Here is the HTML in question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>SPS: Create a new poll</title>
<link href="styles/stylePollCreator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsPollCretor.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

        <div id="pollSetup">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <label for="pollName:">Poll name</label>
                <input type="text" name="pollName" id="pollName" />
                <br />
                <label for="startDate">Start date: </label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="dateSelector" value="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
                <label for="endDate">End date: </label>
                <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="dateSelector" value="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
                <br />
                <div id="pollOptions">
                </div>
                <input id="submitNewPoll" value="Create poll" type="submit" />
            </form>
            <button id="addOption">Add option</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The addOption function is working fine, however the watermark function seems to call once when the site first loads, and then no more :/

thankyou for your time :)

Comment: Don't use `javascript:`-URLs in eventhandler-attributes, but plain code.

Comment: Why in the world aren't you using [the `placeholder` input attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) (and HTML5 polyfill if you want to support older browsers)?!

Comment: Don't use eventhandler-attributes at all when you have jQuery available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`focusin` and `focusout` expect functions for arguments, and you are technically passing `undefined`, since watermark isn't returning anything. In other words, you are passing the result of `watermark`, not `watermark` itself.

So, you want to do this:

```
$('.dateSelector').focusin(function(){watermark(this,1,'DD-MM-YYYY')});
```

**EDIT:**

I agree with the comment above that you should be using the placeholder attribute. So, your input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="pollName" id="pollName" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
```

Keep in mind that this is a HTML5 attribute, so for old browsers, you'll have to use a polyfill, but if you [google placeholder polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=placeholder+polyfill), you'll find a million polyfills that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, to you and mattball. I havn't had much of a look at html 5 yet, so i didn't know placeholder was a thing :P

Answer (score 0):

> however the watermark function seems to call once when the site first loads

Yes, that is what you are doing with

```
$('.dateSelector').focusin(watermark(this,1,'DD-MM-YYYY'));
$('.dateSelector').focusout(watermark(this,0,'DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

which is equivalent to

```
watermark(this,1,'DD-MM-YYYY');
$('.dateSelector').focusin(undefined);
watermark(this,0,'DD-MM-YYYY');
$('.dateSelector').focusout(undefined);
```

Pass functions to the event registration:

```
$('.dateSelector').focusin(function(e) {
    watermark(this,1,'DD-MM-YYYY');
}).focusout(function(e) {
    watermark(this,0,'DD-MM-YYYY');
});
```

However, as @MattBall already commented, you should just use the `placeholder` attribute and shim it (with an existing library) if you need to support older browsers:

```
<input type="text" name="pollName" id="pollName" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
```